# Slow performance with NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have a security library in C and try to import that into my Android project using NDK. The library depends on three other libraries: pbc, gmp, and openssl. I've built the first two libraries as static libraries and the [last one](https://github.com/eighthave/openssl-android) as shared libraries.

I timed the encrypt() and decrypt() functions in my library.

On my laptop, it is:

- encrypt() 30ms
- decrypt() 160ms

On my Android device(Droid 2.2.3), it is:

- encrypt() 190ms
- decrypt() 1300ms

The time is only for calling those two functions from the C library. The JNI overhead is very small.

Is this expected?

### Update:

Both encrypt() and decrypt() do not have any IO operation, mainly float point operation. And I compiled the code for armeabi-v7a.

Comment: It depends on what those two functions do.

Comment: But what is involved? Do you expect us to guess what are you calulating there?

Comment: ... so, I take it your laptop doesn't have a substantially more powerful processor than the Android device has?

Comment: What it does is to encrypt and decrypt arbitrary length char array using SHA256(openssl) and arbitrary precision arithmetic(gmp).

Comment: Pls write what hw do you have in your Laptop, and what phone do you have?
It can be possible because the hw difference of the machines. Android Phone has very different architecture of CPU than the laptop. It maybe not accelerates encryption as level as the x86 CPU can (SSE, SSE2, SSE3, etc)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all I would say that you are lucky - your port works only 8 times slower than laptop version. It is quite a good result for ARM-based platforms.

There are several reasons to be slower on ARM:

- ARM processors simply have less computational power than Intel/AMD desktop CPUs
- Slower memory and lower bandwidth
- Different architectural restrictions (for example floating point unit is separated from integer CPU core in ARM)

You can try the following things to improve the performance of you code:

- If your phone has modern FPU then you can try to recompile all the libraries with additional compiler flag `-mfpu=vfpv3` (or `-mfpu=neon`). It can slightly improve the speed of floating-point calculations because of doubled number of FPU registers.
- Try to build your code with newer compiler. [Latest Crystax NDK](http://www.crystax.net/en/android/ndk) which is modified version of Google NDK includes gcc 4.6 toolchain. Sometimes newer compiler can produce more effective code.
- Profile your code and optimize bottlenecks. You can use a number of arm specific optimization tricks ([here is](http://www.davespace.co.uk/arm/efficient-c-for-arm/index.html) a bit outdated but good guide) or vertorize code with NEON SIMD.

Comment: I tested it on Nexus S and the time dropped to half of the original. Droid's 600MHz processor is just too slow :(